# NSScrollView with massive contentView causing terrible performance on scroll

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsscrollview

I'm trying to draw a large waveform/graph that is an `NSView` placed inside of a `NSScrollView`. That way, the user can scroll horizontally and parts of it at a time.

The waveform view can be very large (technically, infinitely wide).

If the entire waveform is drawn, the scrolling performance is unusable. I'm unsure why `NSScrollView` is attempting to redraw the entire view rather than just the visible rect - but I suspect I will need to implement this logic myself.

What is the most efficient way to implement this to have a good scrolling experience?

Comment: Does `NSScrollView` ask you to draw the entire view or do you draw the entire view when asked to draw the dirty part? Is creating an image of the graph an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could **tile** the contents of your scroll view into several small `NSView` instances, each one representing a small part of your graph and placed right beside one another.

However, I am not sure to what extent the views that are clipped off-screen still consume resources and affect performance.

A better apporach would be similar to the above, but relying on the built-in functionality of a **Collection View**. Its machinery definitely takes care of displaying only the cells that should be visible (not clipped by the scroll view).

Comment: Collection view crossed my mind as well - but shouldn't a scroll view have the same built in mechanism without tiling? Some method like scrollView:willShowRect: or something like that?

Comment: If your graph is one single monolithic NSView, it's an all-or-nothing thing:  NSView itself does not support optimizations for partially occluded display, except perhaps `drawRect:`...

Comment: I don't know the details of how the contents of your NSView are created, but  splitting into tiles gives the system a better chance to work on smaller data.

Comment: Well, as  you mentioned `NSView` has `drawRect:` which presumably when coupled with `NSClipView` (part of `NSScrollView`), should only trigger a draw for the portion which is visible!

Comment: Yes... Are you implementing that method, and caluclating only the visible portion of your graph there? `drawRect:` puts that kind of optimization in your hands; it makes it your responsibility. But I haven't seen the code where you actually "draw" the graph, so can't say for sure.

Comment: That is true.  I am using another library to render the graph so my guess is t hey didn't implement that method properly.